# How to use gfx module in python

Tags: python, module, installation, gfx

I'm trying to use the gfx module for python (from here: http://www.swftools.org/gfx_tutorial.html). But when I do `python setup.py build` I get an error:

> ImportError: cannot import name CompileError

I just need to open a gfx file.. (Its part of the pythonchallenge.com)
How can I do it?

I'm working on linux mint 64bit

Comment: have you tried sudo python setup.py build ?

Comment: Tried now, same thing

Comment: does the "python setup.py install" not run ?

Comment: It runs, but I get the 'cannot import name CompileError' error

Comment: @JaviDorfsman do `python2 -m trace --trace setup.py build > debug.log` and give us the last hundred or so lines of **debug.log**, paste it in https://gist.github.com/ or something similar.

Comment: exported it to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/p1zvJx4h

Comment: Did this end up working for you? I'm struggling through this same setup process.

Comment: No, couldn't make it work

Comment: Hmmm, did you find a work around in terms of opening the .gfx file?

Comment: I must say I don't even remember for what I needed it..

Comment: Oh, was it not for the pythonchallenge.com (#12)?

Comment: Oh yeah! sorry, I still don't remember what I did..

Comment: Without giving too much away: That `gfx` module has _nothing_ to do with that pythonchallenge and is _not_ required for solving it.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks! The "setup.py" file at their repository is even outdated( "print" is still a statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download

```
http://www.swftools.org/download.html
```

You can build the Python module using setup.py
You can build it "manually" by using make
To do the former, all that should be required is

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

This is the preferred way. If the above gives you any trouble or you prefer make, the following will also create the Python module:

```
./configure
make
# substitute the following path with your correct python 
installation:
cp lib/python/*.so /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/
```

You can test whether the python module was properly installed by doing

```
python -c 'import gfx'
```

Comment: Great! That did it.

Answer (score 3):

`enter code here` Not sure how stable this is but there seems to be a lot of issues installing  0.9.2 on ubuntu:

```
wget http://www.swftools.org/swftools-2013-04-09-1007.tar.gz
tar -xzvf swftools-2013-04-09-1007.tar.gz 
cd swftools-2013-04-09-1007/
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo cp lib/python/*.so /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

That should compile and install on ubuntu.
Then  `python -c 'import gfx'` should work.

I had a look at the `setup.py` script and it seems it is using `CompileError` from `distutils` which is now depreciated, I replaced it with `from distutils.core import  CCompilerError`

Running python setup.py runs after changing but complains about various errors in relation to `jpeg` and `PIL._imaging.so` so I have included an `instuctions.txt` in the file which has instructions on how to setup the required packages and symlinks etc...

I also had to add the lib/art directory from [swftools on github](https://github.com/brad/swftools/tree/master/lib/art) and add it to the `lib` directory.

It runs and installs on `ubuntu 14.04` but should work on `mint` also.

The updated package is [here](https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B4DUA4J0f2IVZmhISXdBS2ZSYVU)

Comment: I'm getting this error: 'cp: cannot stat ‘lib/python/*.so’: No such file or directory' and there are really no .so files in that folder

Comment: have you compiled as above with no errors? It is working for me on ubuntu. The examples are working also. You are also putting the lines in one by one yes?

Comment: what do you get after `sudo make install`

Comment: when you cd into `lib/python` there is no `gfx.so`?

Comment: No, there is just gfx.c

Comment: my output is identical and it creates the.so

Comment: Well.. mine doesn't.. Is it unique? could you maybe send it to me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55206/discussion-between-padraic-cunningham-and-javi-dorfsman).